# org mode - add formula to generate delta column

Tags: org-mode, org-table

How can I get below result with org table formula? The number of rows maybe too many, so doing it line by line is not good way.

For example:

```
@1$2 = @1$1 - @1$1
@2$2 = @2$1 - @1$1
@3$2 = @3$1 - @2$1
...

| x | delta |
|---+-------|
| 2 |     0 |
| 3 |     1 |
| 5 |     2 |
| 1 |    -4 |
| 7 |     6 |
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using Calc’s logical operations to handle the first row:

```
| x | delta |
|---+-------|
| 2 |     0 |
| 3 |     1 |
| 5 |     2 |
| 1 |    -4 |
| 7 |     6 |
#+tblfm: $2=@# < 3 ? 0 : $1-@-1$1
```

Explanation:

- Org-tables understand Calc expressions (see `(info "(org) Formula syntax for Calc")`). The `if` expression uses the syntax `condition ? then-part : else-part`.
- `@#`, the current row's index number, is being substituted before `calc-eval`. `@# < 3` tests whether the current row's index is less than 3.
- `$1` refers to the current row in column 1. `@-1$1` takes the value in column 1 with current row's index minus 1 (the cell one row above). The else part subtracts the value in the cell above from the value in the current row's cell.

Comment: Can you please add some notes about your formula. It is super crisp (+1 for that) and would be nice to know how to works!

Answer (score 5):

As follows:

```
| x | delta |
|---+-------|
| 2 |     0 |
| 3 |     1 |
| 5 |     2 |
| 1 |    -4 |
| 7 |     6 |
#+TBLFM: @2$2=0::@3$2..@>$2=@0$1-@-1$1
```

The entry `@2$2`, row 2 column 2, has to be set separately.  Otherwise `@3$2..@>$2`, rows 3 to last, column 2, is set to `@0$1` (current row, column 1) minus `@-1$1` (previous row, column 1).  Details of mechanisms for referencing different cells may be found in the `Org Mode` info page, under `The spreadsheet`, available via `C-h i` or at [the online version](http://orgmode.org/manual/The-spreadsheet.html)